# How do I get the value of CORS allowed origin from spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Given the YAML fragment

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
```

How do I use `@Value("${spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.???.allowedOrigins")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.'[/**]'.allowed-origins=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.'[/**]'.allowed-methods=HEAD,OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.'[/**]'.allowed-headers=*
```

Comment: for allowed-origins=* you can use allowed-origins[0]=*