# How do I set the value of CORS allowed origin for Spring Cloud Gatweay from the environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Complements [How do I get the value of CORS allowed origin from spring cloud gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050120/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-cors-allowed-origin-from-spring-cloud-gateway)

What environment variable would map to the following point?

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*" # << how do I change this?
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon OS, the key might not be allowed, but the one of the option would be to use `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`. Check [externalize configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Lets say you have following properties

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
```

Convert this yaml to json. For [eg](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json)

```
{
  "spring": {
    "cloud": {
      "gateway": {
        "globalcors": {
          "corsConfigurations": {
            "[/**]": {
              "allowedOrigins": "*",
              "allowedHeaders": "*",
              "allowedMethods": [
                "GET",
                "POST"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Trim any white spaces for [eg using](https://www.browserling.com/tools/remove-all-whitespace)

```
{"spring":{"cloud":{"gateway":{"globalcors":{"corsConfigurations":{"[/**]":{"allowedOrigins":"*","allowedHeaders":"*","allowedMethods":["GET","POST"]}}}}}}}
```

Now in your env variable you can set

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON = '{"spring":{"cloud":{"gateway":{"globalcors":{"corsConfigurations":{"[/**]":{"allowedOrigins":"*","allowedHeaders":"*","allowedMethods":["GET","POST"]}}}}}}}'
```

You can write some kind of CLI script to do this.