How to resolve invalid character included yaml attributes from kubernetes
I need to dynamically add cors allowedOrigins from value.yaml for kubernetes container. here is my value.yaml
 test:
  cors:
    allowedOrigins: 'https://www.test.com'

And I was trying to override below attribute.
spring:
  application:
    name: something
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: 'https://www.host.com'

And i tried to resolve it like this below.
- name: SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS_[/**]_ALLOWEDORIGINS
  value: {{ .Values.test.cors.allowedOrigins | quote }}

Btw it says that I can't use [/**] this since it is invalid. I'm getting this error

SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS_[/**]ALLOWEDORIGINS": a valid environment variable name must consist of alphabetic characters, digits, '', '-', or '.', and must not start with a digit (e.g. 'my.env-name', or 'MY_ENV.NAME', or 'MyEnvName1', regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z][-._a-zA-Z0-9]*')

How can I make it work?

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080211

Not quite sure. The issue is I need to override the spring allowedOrigin using an env value yml. But I cannot refer that value due to the [/**] attribute.

The question @tobifasc refers to suggests that you can put JSON-encoded Spring configuration into SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON, which might work here.  In the past I've also put YAML-formatted Spring configuration into a ConfigMap, mounted it, and loaded that via SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONALLOCATION.

I found a better way to solve this.
Here is my Value.yaml
test:
  cors:
    allowedOrigins: 'https://www.test.com'

And this is was in my microservice which I needed to override.
spring:
  application:
    name: something
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: ${GATEWAY_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS:*}

And this is the value mapping in deployment yaml.
- name: GATEWAY_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
  value: {{ default "*" (.Values.test.cors.allowedOrigins) | quote }} 

To do this, it helped me the comments I received for this question. So Thanks for the comments.
